# Python with Framework7 for building mobile applications?

Tags: javascript, python, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I'm a beginner with some experience in Python and and basic knowledge of Javascript. I really like Python and I was wondering if there is some way I could leverage my Python knowledge to build apps with Framework7 and Cordova which requires Javascript? I don't want to go to the Kivy route for now because Framework7 has some pretty advanced User Interface components so I was interested in that. I heard there are couple of ways like **Pyjs** and **Transcrypt** that could convert my Python code to Javascript. Is it by any chance possible to do so? Or there are any other ways to build mobile applications using Python without Kivy, I would be very interested in knowing that.  Thank you!!

Comment: Did you try Framework7 with Transcrypt? I think it would work, but didn’t try it yet.